# Any plugin installation and update overwrite current theme

Tags: plugins, themes, child-theme, server

I'm facing a strange situation. I have a website with custom theme and custom child theme active and every time I try to update or install a plugin via admin interface, the plugin extracted files completely overwrite the child theme folder.

The website is hosted on an Ubuntu Server 22.04 on MS Azure.

The same website on a development server performs installations and updates regularly.

I'm quite sure the issue depends on the server configuration, but it's specifically related to WordPress.

So, could anyone of you point me the right direction to get rid of this issue, please?

Comment: Any chance you've hooked something that returns file paths, perhaps temporarily because you were having trouble installing or updating the child theme? Although I guess not if it works in the dev environment :-/

Comment: There's no symlinks on the production server to combine the two folders for some reason?

Comment: and there are no other differences, e.g. something edited in the WordPress core files, or in wp-config.php, or a stray mu-plugin?

Comment: @Rup no hooks that return file paths for sure. As you mentioned, in the dev environment I don't get the issue. As far as I know, no symlinks or stray mu-plugins on the production server, but I'm checking another time. Same wp-config except for FS_DIRECT. Thanks for now